# proving series convergence by definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a question in the homework, and I tried to prove it
but I don't know if it is correct?

I want to prove that the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n(n+1)}
$$
is absolutely convergent for $|z|\le 1$.

My answer is by Abel's Theorem:

$$\left|\frac{z^n}{n(n+1)} \right| \lt \frac{1}{n^2}$$
which is convergent series , thus our series is absolutely convergent
Is This  True ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the comparison test.
$$\left|\dfrac{z^n}{n(n+1)}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
Use also the fact that the sum $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$
To simply prove that $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges, use the integral test.

Comment: The fact that $\sum n^{-2}$ is finite is enough, the exact value is irrelevant.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes. I added the value to show that the sum converges.

Comment: but he ask me to prove it

Comment: @HamadaAl See my edited answer.

Comment: I think you talk about testing convergence not proving ??

Comment: @HamadaAl Using the integral test shows that $\sum n^{-2}$ is convergent. That is enough for proving the convergence of your series.

Comment: I want to prove by ($\epsilon$-$N$)

Comment: @HamadaAl It's a sum, not a sequence.

Comment: we can,t prove the convergence of the series by this method !!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Follows just by comparison to $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ as you showed; Abel's theorem is not needed.

Comment: Abel's theorem is needed to proving but not for testing . I think that .